# Delete the pendrive contents and also trash in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, macbook, usb-flash-drive, trash

I am using a MacBook Pro.  I copied some data from my pen drive to my Mac and deleted the content by moving it to trash.  After that when I see the info of pen drive it give more value than the original value.  If I cleaned the content of the trash only I am able to see the correct value of pen drive and able to copy data.

Has Mac been designed like that or is there some other way to delete other than using the "move to trash" option? Thanks.

Comment: it's not quite clear what you're asking.  what value are you checking?  when does it change, when moving files to the trash or after emptying the trash?

Comment: After emptying the trash it gives the correct size of the flash drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trash for the pendrive is stored in a hidden `.Trashes` folder on the pendrive. Therefore, initially moving a file to Trash will not recover the space on the drive. Emptying the trash will delete items in the trash on all mounted volumes, including the pendrive. That is when you will see your recovered space. That feature is by design in OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I have found myself periodically formatting my pen drive via Disk Utility to keep things clean. Emptying the Trash will do the job, but somehow this ensures it.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. In spotlight type “Disk utility”.

Step 2. Select on drive to be deleted.

Step 3. On right pop up select the disks to be edited.

Step 4. Choose “Erase” tab on top right Click on “Erase Free Space” on
    bottom left of box (it will be disable till file are deleted)